# String indices must be integers, new to python

Tags: python, wordpress

I hope I won't get trashed for this question. This is my *first* day with Python and all I've done so far is copy pasting and deducing from other snippets of code. I have no experience with code. I'm trying my hardest however this one I can't get past for the past few hours.

I'm currently adjusting an Editorial (iOS app) workflow to fit my needs — namely: posting to my WordPress site, including the ability to choose from a list of all possible post formats (I have "standard" and "link" enabled).

Here is the faulty bit from the relevant Python script:

```
console.show_activity('Fetching formats...')

server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(wp_url)

format = server.wp.getPostFormats(wp_blogid, wp_username, wp_password, 'post_format')


i = 0
for x in format:
        formats += '\n' + x['name'] + " " + str(i)
        i = i+1

workflow.set_variable("formats", formats)
console.hide_activity()
```

I'm getting the error: "string indices must be integers, not str"

What is this supposed to do is later show me in a list my available formats. I've done this successfully with `server.wp.getPostFormats(wp_blogid, wp_username, wp_password, 'post_tag')` and `server.wp.getTerms(wp_blogid, wp_username, wp_password, 'category')`

I know my problem is where the line with the `i` starts, I just have no idea how to solve it. I'm assuming by reading other topics that I need to cast, but I'm not even sure what `getPostFormats` returns, or how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've now concluded that `server.wp.getPostFormats` returns a dictionary, but I have not a slightest idea on how to retrieve only one set of data (either the key or value) of this dictionary. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because "string indices must be integers, not str".

```
    formats += '\n' + x['name'] + " " + str(i)
```

Here, you are accessing the 'name'th element of `x`, where `'name'` is of course a string and x is a string too, since `server.wp.getPostFormats` obviously returns a list of strings.

So simply look at `format` and you should immediately see how to obtain the required data.

**UPDATE:**

OK, so you figured out that `format` is a dictionary (returned from `server.wp.getPostFormats`). In Python, if you iterate over a dictionary (your for-loop), you iterate through its keys. This is the standard behaviour.

Look at this example:

```
>>> foo = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> for x in foo: print(x)
... 
a
c
b
```

Of course you also need the values, not only the keys (you seem to look for an entry with the key `name`). One way is to iterate though the keys and items in one shot:

```
>>> for key, value in foo.iteritems():
...     print(key + ":" + str(value))
... 
a:1
c:3
b:2
```

So the `.iteritems()` method of a dictionary returns for every iteration a key/value-pair, which you can unpack within the for loops definition.

In your case, you can do the following:

```
for key, value in format.iteritems():
    formats += 'key: ' + key + ', value: ' + value + '\n'
```

Comment: Immediately. Hmm…the most I've done is CSS up until now. I wanted to take a few guesses but I'm clueless to be honest. I know this looks like laziness but it isn't.

Comment: I'm still trying to fix this. Can you offer an expanded explanation perhaps? Am I dealing with a dictionary? How do I split the keys from the values and only display the latter?

Comment: Why wouldn't formats = format work? If format is already a list of strings by now?

Comment: Of course it could work. Try `formats += '\n' + x + " " + str(i)`. OK, so since CSS is not a programming language (although some basic techniques in the workflow are the same), you have to learn how to debug your own code. If you don't know what a variable holds, you can simply try it out in the Python console or put a `print(x)` in your code to look at it at runtime. Just like when you do `border: 1px solid red` if you want to highlight an element in CSS to see its bounds ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the principles, but the code above worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are new, I would also suggest using the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) method and refactoring your code:

```
for i, x in enumerate(format):
    formats += '\n' + x[idx_for_name] + " " + str(i)
```

The `idx_for_name` would be the index for the name.

If you wanna go even further, you can use the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method too:

```
formats = '\n'.join(x[idx_for_name] + " " + str(i) \
                        for i, x in enumerate(format))
```

*warning*: This code is untested.

Comment: I don't even know where to put it, or instead of what. My level of understanding is way too basic. Am I creating a new variable here?

Comment: How do i know what should `idx_for_name` should be? Is there a way to know the index for the name?

Comment: No no, formats and types are entirely different things in WordPress. If I change the type, it changes nothing about the format. What I simply need from this dictionary is the names to be displayed in a list, even if untidly. I just don't know how to "extract" only one set of the items and display it.

Comment: How about `format['supported']`? Isn't that the list of the formats. The real question is, what are you expecting to receive?

Comment: I don't even care if it's the key or name that are used (since they are the same only the value is capitalized). I just have no idea how to get either of these to be stored as the variable formats.

Comment: I'm not sure what piece of code you're referring to when you say format['supported']? What does that do? I really have no idea about Python? Where would I append that to format? Editorial is supposed to take the variable 'formats' after that an display it as a list from which I can chose (the format: standard, link, quote, etc..)

Comment: The code in my post worked just fine with categories and tags and Editorial displayed the options correctly. But they return a list ( a string? I don't know) no a dictionary which has 2 sets of info for each item.

Comment: The docs say they return a dictionary with two keys, `all` and `supported`, if you want the `standard, link, quote, ...` part, you can get that from `format['all'].keys()`. Don't take my word for it though, I am not testing this, or have any working code, I am just following the docs.

Comment: Can you tell me how I should implement it in my code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Read:
http://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/methods.html#wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts.GetPostFormats

GetPostFormats return a dictionary so x iterates among the keys which are strings.

Try:

```
x= format['all']:
```

Comment: Should I add this just after i=0?